# Is every left-unique relation right-uniqe?

Tags: relations

Lets say we have a relation A x B.
As far as I unterstood, in a right-unique relation, for every element from A, there is *at least* one element in B. But there might be elements in B which do not have a "partner" in A.

My understanding of left-unique is, that *every* element from B has only *one* partner in A.

So, when a Relation is left-unique, it has to be right-unique.
Is this correct, or did I messed something up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [right-unique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Special_types_of_binary_relations) relation between $A$ and $B$ means $\forall a \in A, a$ is related to at most one $b \in B$.

A [left-unique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Special_types_of_binary_relations) relation between $A$ and $B$ means $\forall b \in B$, at most one $a \in A$ is related to $b$.

Example of a left-unique relation that is not right-unique:

$$A = \{1,2,3\}, \quad B = \{4,5,6\}$$
$$R = \{(1,4),\,(1,5)\}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I always misread left-unique so that every element HAS to have one in A. Your simple example showed me my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing unique with a [serial relation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_relation). However for this the property still doesn't hold. Take A = B = {0,1} and R = {<0, 0>, <1, 0>}; i.e., xRy if and only if y = 0. This relation is serial in x but not in y.