# Translating from English sentences to an axiomatic system in Typed First Order Logic

Tags: first-order-logic

I am trying to express the following axiomatic system (theory) in the language of typed first order logic (FOL).

There are at least two cities.
For any two distinct cities, there is exactly one track connecting them.
No train track connect all cities.
Given any track T and any city C not on T, there is exactly one track  on which C lies, but none of the cities on T are on this track.

Below is my attempt. I  used the predicate $track(x,y)$ which is true when there is a track from $x$ to $y$ :

**1.** There are at least two cities.

$\exists x,y:City (x \neq  y)$

**2.** For any two distinct cities, there is exactly one track connecting them (using [left and right uniqueness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945874/is-every-left-unique-relation-right-uniqe))

$\forall x,z,w:City  ((x \neq w) \land (x \neq z) \land ((track(x,z) \land track(x,w)) \Rightarrow  (w = z)) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \land   ((track(z,x) \land track(w,x)) \Rightarrow  ( w = z))) $

**3.** No track connects all cities.

$\neg \exists x:City  (\forall y:City \bullet   track(x,y))$ (*Not sure about this!*)

**4.** Given any track T and any city C not on T, there is exactly one track  on which C lies, but none of the cities on T are on this track.(using [unique existential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification))

$\forall x,y,c:City ((track(x,y) \land(c  \neq x) \land (c \neq y )) \Rightarrow (\exists k, \forall j:City  (track(c,k)  \land (k \neq x) \land (k \neq y)) \Rightarrow(j = k)))$

**EDIT: new attempt at formalisation**

Taking into account the suggested solution the tentative models of this theory consist of one or more distinct tracks (or connections) as in **Model 1** or possibly more than one city per track **Model 2**. I will have to reconsider my solution from scratch.

[image: Tentative Models]

Here is a new formalisation following suggestions from user21820

**1**  There are at least two cities.

$\exists x,y:City : (x \neq y)$

**2** For any two distinct cities, there is exactly one track connecting them.

$\forall c1:City, \forall c2:City : (c1 \neq c2) \Rightarrow (\exists t1:Track,  \forall t2:Track : (CityOnTrack(c1,t1) \land CityOnTrack(c2,t1)) \Leftrightarrow (t1 = t2)))$

**3**  No track connects all cities.

$\forall t:Track, \exists c:City : \neg(CityOnTrack(c,t)))$

**4**  Given any track T and any city C not on T, there is exactly one track  on which C lies, but none of the cities on T are on this track,

\begin{align*} 
\forall c:City  ,\forall t:Track : 
&(\neg CityOnTrack(c,t) \Rightarrow  \\
&((\exists t2:Track : CityOnTrack(c,t2)  \land \\
&(\forall c2:City  :(CityOnTrack(c2,t) \Rightarrow \neg CityOnTrack(c2,t2))) \land \\
&(\forall t3:Track,\forall t4:Track, (CityOnTrack(c,t3) \land CityOnTrack(c,t4))))\Rightarrow (t3=t4))).
\end{align*}
For **4** I am not sure if the FOL for "*none of the cities on T are on this track*" is correct or is in the correct position. Also, as suggested by  user21820, I have used the third of the four definitions of  [unique existential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification) from Wikipedia.

**Question**

Is this new formalisation correct?

The original problem is from [A TeXas Style Introduction to Proof](https://www.maa.org/press/books/a-texas-style-introduction-to-proof) ([page 124](https://books.google.ie/books?id=300xDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=There%20are%20at%20least%20two%20cities.%20For%20any%20two%20distinct%20cities,&source=bl&ots=TdO4cP1Rjf&sig=ACfU3U2NxtsdRsFYQbV-kvWCRmXMmVTB1Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPjqGTnrLmAhU-RBUIHX9kCEkQ6AEwCnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=There%20are%20at%20least%20two%20cities.%20For%20any%20two%20distinct%20cities%2C&f=false)).

Comment: For 1, Yes: in "plain" FOL it is : $\exists x \exists y (x \ne y \land City(x) \land City(y))$.

Comment: What is $track(x,y)$ ? If it is a term, you cannot negate it. So, it is a predicate that holds when $x$ and $y$ are connected.

Comment: @Ma Yes track is a predicate.

Comment: If so, your translation of 3 means "there are no Cities that are connected".

Comment: Thanks, My recent edit was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as stated was very unclear, to the point that you misinterpreted what you were required to express. From (3) I guess that a track is not merely a city-to-city connection, but rather a whole long 'line' with some cities on it, possibly more than $2$. So you need to have two types, one for cities and one for tracks. And you would need a predicate to express "city C is on track T". Here are English renderings suitable for translation to FOL:

(1) Fine in the new interpretation.

(2) For every cities X,Y, if they are different then there is a unique track T such that X,Y are both on T.

(3) There is no track T such that every city X is on T.

(4) I'll leave this one to you.

(By the way, colon is an acceptable standard symbol for the typing of quantified objects, but I do not think the big black dot is a standard convention.)

Comment: Thank for your answer. I had not thought of a track with more than 2 cities.

Comment: @PatrickBrowne: Indeed that's why I said the problem was unclear, so it's not really your fault for not thinking of that possibility. I didn't either until I read (3). Feel free to ask to clarify any point, and then if you are satisfied with my answer you can accept it. =)

Comment: Following your suggestions, I have updated my attempt. Any feedback would be welcome.

Comment: @PatrickBrowne: (1) to (3) are correct, and it's interesting how you had expressed uniqueness of objects that satisfy a property P, because it's not either of the two usual ways of doing it: (a) exists an object satisfying P such that every other object satisfying P is equal to it; (b) exists an object satisfying P, and every pair of objects satisfying P are equal. But your attempt for (4) is incorrect, and I think it's partly because of your non-systematic expressing of uniqueness. You might want to try that one again. =)

Comment: I have made another attempt at part 4.

Comment: @PatrickBrowne: If I didn't make a mistake it's correct now based on the most grammatical interpretation of the English sentence. Yes you are right that there is an ambiguity in the English. Yours is the one that agrees most closely with the grammar, because of the comma. If the other interpretation was desired, it should have been phrased as "there is exactly one track U such that C lies on U and no city on T lies on U".

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at my efforts. Your helpful answer and comments are much appreciated.